# when yield a function(yield client.query),why the codes of the function don't execute?

Tags: mysql, node.js, koa

I tried to use nodejs to write some code to read mysql, my code like this:

```
exports.selectport = function*(projectname){
    var strsql = "SELECT DISTINCT portname FROM invoketable where projectname = '"+projectname+"'";
    var rest;
    yield 1;
    yield client.query(strsql, function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
           console.log(err);
           return err;
        }
        rest = results[0].portname;
        console.log(rest);
        return rest;
    });
    yield rest;
}
```

and I used code to call the function:

```
var gen = mysqlinsertp.selectport(dataproject);
var ret = gen.next(); 
console.log(ret.value); // 1
console.log(ret.done); // false
var ret2 = gen.next();
console.log(ret2.value); // Query{...}
console.log(ret2.done); // false
var ret3 = gen.next(); 
console.log(ret3.value); // undefined
console.log(ret3.done); // false
var ret4 = gen.next(); 
console.log(ret4.value); // undefined
console.log(ret4.done); // true
```

I want to know why `rest = results[0].portname; console.log(rest);` did not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're mixing generators and callbacks. 
You would only use yield if this: `client.query(sql)` returns a promise or a thunk, in which case you wouldn't use a callback as you've shown above.

If the library you're using doesn't return promises or thunks, you'd need to either:

```
// yieldable 
let results = yield client.query(sql);
// straight callback
client.query(sql, function(err, results){...});
```

- choose a library that supports promise // yieldable
- Write your own promise wrapper around the callback // easy to lookup
- Just use callbacks and not try to yield // straight callback

Also you're sql is susceptible to sql injection attacks. If the user specifies the project name, they could send a project name like `junk'; DROP TABLE users;` in which case you'd lose your users table, or other tables...
You should escape your parameters or paramertrized queries  `connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT portname FROM invoketable where projectname ?', [project])`